# Customizing ReadXml() of typed DataSet

Tags: c#, .net, xml, dataset

I'm writing some extra information to my strongly-typed `DataSet` and have therefore added a couple of functions named `ReadXmlEx()` and `WriteXmlEx()` to its partial class. Therein, I need to read/write xml using the base class's `ReadXml()` and `WriteXml()` and then appending my own nodes to the output.

My question here is, what is the best way to achieve this? Currently, I'm using the following approach:

```
public void ReadXmlEx(string filename)
{
    System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(filename);
    this.Custom1 = doc.FirstChild.NextSibling.ChildNodes[0].Value;

    //Here I need to move to ChildNodes[1] and pass the remaining tree to base class's ReadXml()
}
```

Reading the comment above, how do I achieve this? Base class's ReadXml() can take a `Stream` object, but I'm not sure how to convert a `ChildNode` to a `Stream` or `XmlReader`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way to convert `XmlNode` (`node`) to `Stream` (`MemoryStream`) :

```
var node = doc.FirstChild.NextSibling.ChildNodes[1];

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms);
sw.Write(node.OuterXml);
sw.Flush();

myDataTable.ReadXml(ms);
```